# How to get sum group by category from product list

Tags: php

I have a list products (includes category and quantity)

```
$html = "";
foreach ($products as $product) {
   $html .= $product->category;
   $html .= $product->name;
   $html .= $product->quantity;
}
echo $html;
```

Follow this list

```
Category | Product | Quantity
Timsum       T1         10
Timsum       T2         20
Timsum       T3         30  
Sauces       S1         5  
Sauces       S2         15
```

How to sum group and show last line each category

```
Category | Product | Quantity
Timsum       T1         10
Timsum       T2         20
Timsum       T3         30 
**Sum Timsum            60**    
Sauces       S1         5  
Sauces       S2         15
**Sum Sauces            20**
```

Comment: are the categories always in order? or can something like `Timsum, Sauces, Timsum` happen?

Comment: Format order by category, like Timsum, Sauces, Chicken, ....

Comment: Did you try out my answer?

Comment: Yes, I'll try. Thanks so much @Webeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `$sum` variable to record the quantities accumulated and making a few conditionals to track when the category has shifted should do the job:

```
$html = "";
$first_iteration = FALSE;
$sum = 0;

foreach ($products as $product) {

   if (!$first_iteration)
   {
      $first_iteration = TRUE;
      $temp_category = $product->category;
   }

   if ($temp_category != $product->category)
   {
      html .= "**".$temp_category;
      html .= $sum;
      $sum = 0;
      $temp_category = $product->category;
   }

   $html .= $product->category;
   $html .= $product->name;
   $html .= $product->quantity;

   $sum += (integer) $product->quantity;
}
html .= "**".$temp_category;
html .= $sum;

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Order the result set by category name, then use temporary variables:

```
$qty = 0;
$last_cat = null;

foreach ($products as $product) {
  if ($product->category != $last_cat && $last_cat) {
    echo "**Sum $last_cat $qty\n";
    $qty = 0;
    $last_cat = $product->category;
  }

  printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",
    $product->category, $product->name, $product->quantity);

  $last_cat = $product->category;
  $qty += $product->quantity;
}
```